# IE is behaving differently when the web app is hosted on IIS 6, compared to IIS 7 & Cassini

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iis, iis-6

I have a web app that works fine from all browsers (IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera & Safari) on my development machine . When I deploy the web app to a test server, IE will start to choke on a particular javascript component (Zoomify).

I can have IE 9 open with the dev hosted web app in one tab and the test server web app in another tab and only the dev hosted app will work. The web app code is exactly the same on both machines, except for the web.config.

The Developer Tools show both sites as being in `Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode: IE9 standards`.

The Zoomify component is failing on the following line:

```
c.onreadystatechange=null
```

with the error:

```
SCRIPT13: Type mismatch
```

What is going on here? Why is IE behaving differently with how it processes Javascript depending on where the web app is hosted?

---

## Update

I've now tested on another server and strangely enough it is working. At this point, the situation is that when the web app is hosted on IIS 6, the javascript file will fail in IE.

A similar issue exists in Opera, but I do not get an error message.

```
Dev Machine
Windows 7
Web Server: Cassini
Status: Working

Test Server 1
Windows Server 2003
Web Server: IIS 6.0
Status: Not working

Test Server 2
Windows Server 2008
Web Server: IIS 7.0
Status: Working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing javascript line `c.onreadystatechange=null` was misleading. Through debugging the Zoomify javascript code, I was able to determine that an error was being generated further up the call stack.

The Zoomify component was attempting to download images for display and was failing due to IE not supporting cross domain calls over the `XMLHttpRequest` object. IE does support cross domain calls using the `XDomainRequest` object. However, the Zoomify component does not provide support for `XDomainRequest`. Opera 11 does not support cross domain calls either.

My workaround for the problem with IE & Opera was to not use cross domain calls and to make the image resources available via a URL on the same domain as the web app.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a path difference in between how the app is deployed between the two different environments...It might cause a bad JS reference 
 Are you using a virtual directory on the test server etc?

Comment: The javascript file is definitely being loaded because the javascript debugger breaks in it. The web app is being hosted in its own website in IIS.

Comment: Does it work when you access the site using localhost directly on the test server? Does it behave just like localhost on your DEV box?

Comment: The test server has IE7 on it, and it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

are you declaring the type on your script element? i think it's either that or if you have http response headers that specify X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

you can ref here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/27/ie9-beta-google-image-search-javascript-content-type-and-nosniff.aspx

Comment: The script is declared as `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ZoomifyImageViewer.min.js"></script>`. There aren't any of those headers on the javascript or HTML file responses.